# Getting database name for user and conference room using IBM domino access service(REST based)

Tags: calendar, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am trying to create an application which consumes/uses REST based service provided by IBM Domino server.
Is there any REST service available , from where I can get all the database name corresponding to user.
There is one http:///api/data , which gives only the database details .
From the client side, I am having username , by getting the username and the database mapping I can get the calendar item of that user by using http:///mail/.nsf/api/calendar/events.

Thanks
Anil

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Data service (i.e., /api/data/...) to read the Domino Directory (names.nsf), which contains the Person document that defines the location of the user's mail file - which is also where the calendar is stored.